# how to remove nested form in angularJS using splice

Tags: angularjs, forms, nested-forms, splice

I have a nested form....where i am able to add new fields fine but am having some trouble deleting the fields.

I want to be able to splice the specific place in my array of objects to delete the fields

currently i have...

html:

```
<div ng-repeat="senarioItem in attendees.formData.scenarios[0].scenarioItems" class="row">
        <div ng-hide="cost._destroy">    
            <div class="form-group col-xs-5">
                <label for="costDescription">Description</label>
                <input class="form-control input-group-lg" type="text" name="costDescription" ng-model="senarioItem.costDescription"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-2">
                <label for="cost">Amount</label>
                <input 
                    class="form-control input-group-lg" 
                    type="number" 
                    name="cost"
                    ng-model="senarioItem.cost"/>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2">
                <a ng-click="removeCost()" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">X</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

controller:

```
attendees.removeCost = function(){
            var cost = attendees.formData.scenarios[0].scenarioItems[index];
            if(cost.id) {
                cost._destroy = true;
            } else {
                attendees.cost.splice(index, 1);
            }


        var cost = attendees.formData.scenarios[0].scenarioItems[index];
    };
```

JSON:

```
"scenarioItems": [
        {
          "cost": "",
          "costDescription": "",
        },
        {
          "cost": "",
          "costDescription": ""
        },
        {
          "cost": "",
          "costDescription": ""
        },
        {
          "cost": "",
          "costDescription": ""
        }
      ]
```

Answer (score 0):

pass the index as parameter to the function

```
<div class="col-md-2">
   <a ng-click="removeCost($index)" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">X</a>
</div>
```

then remove it in the function

```
attendees.removeCost = function(index){
            var cost = attendees.formData.scenarios[0].scenarioItems[index];
            if(cost.id) {
                cost._destroy = true;
            } else {
                attendees.cost.splice(index, 1);
            }


        var cost = attendees.formData.scenarios[0].scenarioItems[index];
};
```